# unable to connect to another computer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

hello guyz i have made a bare bone program in C# that simply sends a message from server to client.

Now i have successfully tested both programs running on the same machines. However when i attempt to connect 2 different computers on different networks it sends me the unable to connect message.

Here the server code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace chat_client_console
{
    class Program
    {
        static TcpListener listener;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*
            string name = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPAddress[] address = Dns.GetHostAddresses(name);


            foreach(IPAddress addr in address)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(addr);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(address[2].ToString());*/
            Console.WriteLine("server");
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 2055);

            listener.Start();

            Socket soc = listener.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection successful");
            Stream s = new NetworkStream(soc);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);

            sw.AutoFlush = true;
            sw.WriteLine("A test message");
            sw.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Test message delivered. Now ending the program");

            /*
            string name = Dns.GetHostName();
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            //IPHostEntry ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(name);
            //Console.WriteLine(ip.AddressList[0].ToString());
            IPAddress[] adr=Dns.GetHostAddresses(name);
            foreach (IPAddress adress in adr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(adress);
            }
            */
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

and here the client code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace chat_client_console_client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string host_ip_address;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter server ip address");
            host_ip_address=Console.ReadLine();
            string display;
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(host_ip_address, 2055);
            Stream s = client.GetStream();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection successfully received");

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
            sw.AutoFlush = true;
            /*while (true)
            {

                display = sr.ReadLine();

                if (display == "")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("breaking stream");
                    break;
                }

            }*/

            display = sr.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(display);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

now when i enter the 127.0.0.1 in the client program it successfully connects to the server and the message is received.

However when i enter my external ip address in the client program running on another computer i am unable to connect.

Suggestions are required in this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: are the ports opened in the firewall(s)?

Comment: i think so both computer are able to ping each other...

Comment: make sure you disable the firewalls and virusscanners for testing this. to make sure it's in your own code and not something external thats playing you :)

Comment: pinging has nothing to do with firewalls.

Comment: Pinging (which is ICMP) and communicating through TCP are completely different things. Sounds like a firewall problem... make sure you open up port 2055 on the server and that the client can do outbound connections

Comment: hmmm now that presents a problem because the other machine is at my friend's house and he isn't exactly pro in forwarding ports and unblocking firewalls. So i just want to know that should my program be theoretically able to connect, i mean is it free from other problems besides port forwarding and firewalls ?

Comment: come on guyz can somebody please verify that nothing is wrong with my code.

Comment: @SomeBody [Access remotely](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) to your friend's computer and open/forward the ports.

Comment: can you telnet on port 2055, that would indicate whether the port is being blocked at the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wireshark in the client computer and look up any tcp packet to make sure the message sent to server.